Efficient way to process video stream with JavaCV FFMPEG
I try to build a Java application that is processing the live stream of a camera, and then stream the processed content to somewhere else. I implemented so far something that is working but I think it is very inefficient from memory point of view.
This is mainly my approach:
  private void processCamera() {
    try (FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = buildGrabber();
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024 * 1024);
      FFmpegFrameRecorder frameRecorder = buildRecorder(frameGrabber, output)) {

     frameGrabber.start();
     frameRecorder.start();

     Frame frame;

     while (frame = frameGrabber.grab() != null) {
       Frame analyzedFrame = analyzeFrame(frame);
       frameRecorder.setTimestamp(frameGrabber.getTimestamp());
       frameRecorder.record(analyzedFrame);

       if (output.size() > 0) {
         outputHelper.sendData(output.toByteArray());
         outputHelper.reset();
       }

      frame.close();
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {}
  }

  private FFmpegFrameGrabber buildGrabber() throws FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception {
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(URL);
    frameGrabber.setFormat("rtsp");
    frameGrabber.setOption("hwaccel", "cuda");
    frameGrabber.setOption("rtsp_transport", "tcp");
    frameGrabber.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

    return frameGrabber;
  }

  private FFmpegFrameRecorder buildRecorder(
      FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber, ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
    FFmpegFrameRecorder frameRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(outputStream, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frameRecorder.setFormat("webm");
    frameRecorder.setFrameRate(frameGrabber.getFrameRate());
    frameRecorder.setOption("hwaccel", "cuda");
    frameRecorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    frameRecorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_VP8);
    frameRecorder.setVideoOption("deadline", "realtime");
    frameRecorder.setVideoOption("cpu-used", "8");
    frameRecorder.setVideoBitrate(2200000);
    frameRecorder.setOption("bufsize", "1M");
    frameRecorder.setOption("output_queue_size", "1024");
    frameRecorder.setOption("cluster_time_limit", "3000");
    frameRecorder.setOption("cluster_size_limit", "1M");
    frameRecorder.setOption("input_queue_size", "1024");
    return frameRecorder;
  }


So the main idea is that I grab frames continuously, analyze them, and record using the FFmpegFrameRecorder, when when enough data is gathered into output, then we send it forward.
The process is working but my application is taking up to 20 GB RAM (reported by top command). I am new to this video processing area and I am not sure why that much memory is used.
I tried to look into heapdumps, and byte[] seems to be the thing that takes the most memory. Also, I looked at memory evolution using VisualVM, and this is how memory is evolving in time:

As you can see, every time it goes higher and higher, until at some point it will crash, or freeze my PC.
I'm not used to this kind of problems, so if anyone has any ideas what the problem could be, or if there is a better way to implement what I need, I am open to suggestions.
In my case, do I really have to use the frameRecorder? Is there a better way to implement this functionality in Java?
